# Add DropDownList in array menu

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to add new links to a menu, but the way it is done today, it is declared in an array.
TypeScript:

```
import { MenuItem } from './menu-item';

export const MENU: MenuItem[] = [
    { name: 'Menu1', link: 'menu1'},
    { name: 'Menu2', link: 'menu2'},
    { name: 'Menu3', link: 'Menu3'},
    { name: 'Menu4', link: 'menu4'}
]
```

Component:

```
import { MENU } from './menu';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-menu',
      templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
    })
    export class MenuComponent {

      routeFragment = '';
      menu: MenuItem[] = MENU;

      constructor(private router: Router) { 
        this.router.events.subscribe(
          e => {
            if(e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
              this.checkRoute(e.url);
            }})}

      checkRoute(url: string) {
        const barIndex = url.indexOf('/', 1);
        if(barIndex === -1) {
          this.routeFragment = url;
        } else {
          this.routeFragment = url.substring(0, barIndex);
        }}}
```

This constant MENU is used to be called up on all screens. But, as it is done today, it is possible to open only one link. I needed to insert a new registration link, but with several options, for example: Menu4 opens submenu 1 submenu 2 submenu 3 ... each with its link

Is it possible to do this, as it is developed today? If not, how?

Comment: translation to english? :)

Comment: Ok, it is translated